# Remove pill shape when active material bottom tabs

Tags: react-native, expo

Im using @react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs and im experiencing an issue with the icons in the tab navigator. The problem is there is a weird background showing up right behind the icon and the padding is way too big, this is how it looks like:

[image]

Im trying to remove the background from the icon but so far no options seem to work.

```
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs";
import { ColorCodes } from "../helper/palette";
import ViewHome from "../views/home";
import MaterialCommunityIcons from "react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons";

const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

export default function RouteTab() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="ViewHome"
      barStyle={{
        backgroundColor: ColorCodes.backgroundDeepest,
      }}
      labeled={false}
      activeColor={ColorCodes.activeColor}
      inactiveColor={ColorCodes.inactiveColor}
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="ViewHome"
        component={ViewHome}
        options={{
          tabBarOptions: {
            style: {
              backgroundColor: "blue",
            },
          },
          tabBarLabel: "Home",
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="qwwqdqwd"
        component={ViewHome}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: "Home",
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with Material Bottom Tabs Navigator v6.x and solution for me was to add this :

`import { useTheme } from 'react-native-paper';`

and in my bottom tab component :

`const theme = useTheme();`

`theme.colors.secondaryContainer = "transparent"`

Edit :

You can do this using a better way like this :

`import {DefaultTheme, Provider as PaperProvider} from 'react-native-paper';`

Then you can update the DefaultTheme using destructuration :

```js
const myNavigationTheme = {
  ...DefaultTheme,
  colors: {
    ...DefaultTheme.colors,
    notification: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)',
    secondaryContainer: 'transparent',
  },
};
```

Finally, just wrap your app with the `PaperProvider` and your updated theme:

```js
<PaperProvider theme={myNavigationTheme}>
  <App />
</PaperProvider>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is coming from `react-native-paper`, You'll need to downgrade this package to version: `^4.12.5`.

```
"react-native-paper": "^4.12.5",
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. @Julien Lamalle answer in detail. Wrap your app using **PaperProvider** and the use **useTheme** to provide colors of your choice.

```
import { useTheme } from 'react-native-paper';
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
import {Provider as PaperProvider} from 'react-native-paper';
import {useTheme} from 'react-native-paper';

export default function Main() {
 const theme = useTheme();

 theme.colors.secondaryContainer = 'transparent';
 return (
 <PaperProvider>
  <App />
</PaperProvider>
);
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => Main);
```